# JSTL to iterate map

Tags: html, dictionary, jstl, iteration, custom-tags

am using JSTL to get values from the bean class . 
The values am getting from the bean class will be of **java.util.Map** . am success in getting the values by the below code :

```
<c:forEach items="${bean.map}" var="item">  
  <c:out value="${item.key}"/> = <c:out value="${item.value}"/><br/>  
</c:forEach>
```

After getting the key-value pair , i need to create a table with 4 rows and 7 columns. 
Map :

```
map.put(2, true);
map.put(18, true);
```

The key in the map will be of from 1-28 and the values will be TRUE or FALSE .

If the key is 2 and the value is TRUE , ineed to place a check mark in (1,2) of the table ie: 1st row 2nd column .

Likewise , if the key is 18 , need to place a check mark in (3,4) of the table .

```
         <table border="1" width="100%">
         <tr>
         <th>1</th>
         <th>2</th>
         <th>3</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>5</th>
         <th>6</th>
         <th>7</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${bean.map}" var="item" >
        <tr>
       <td><c:out value="${item.value}"/></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

I dont know how to proceed further , since i am restricted to use only JSTL and am new to JSTL . Am not allowed to use javascriptor jquery which makes the life easy .

Kindly give me some suggestion to proceed further . Any help will be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

Split your entries into rows, using Java code, in your controller instead of wanting to do it using JSTL in the view. It's possible, but everything will be easier by doing it in Java.

And using a map to contain keys going from 1 to 28 is a bit strange. Why not just use a list of 28 boolean?

```
/**
 * Returns a list of 4 lists of booleans (assuming the map contains 28 entries going 
 * from 1 to 28). Each of the 4 lists contaisn 7 booleans.
 */
public List<List<Boolean>> partition(Map<Integer, Boolean> map) {
    List<List<Boolean>> result = new ArrayList<List<Boolean>>(4);
    List<Boolean> currentList = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
        if ((i - 1) % 7 == 0) {
            currentList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(7);
            result.add(currentList);
        }
        currentList.add(map.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And in your JSP:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
         <th>1</th>
         <th>2</th>
         <th>3</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>5</th>
         <th>6</th>
         <th>7</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="row">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach items="row" var="value">            
                <td><c:out value="${value}"/></td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```